# docker is great for run-anywhere but what about the machines to host docker?

Tags: docker, deployment

I am wondering how do we make machines that host docker to be easily replaceable.  I would like something like a `Dockerfile` that contains instructions on how to set-up the machine that will host docker.  Is there a way to do that?

The naive solution would be to create an official "docker host" binary image to install on new machines, but I would like to have something that is reproducible and transparent like the dockerfile?

It seems like tools like Vagrant, Puppet, or Chef may be useful but they appear to be for virtual machine procurement and they seem to all require set-up of some sort of "master node" server.  I am not going to be spinning up and tearing down regularly so a master server is a waste of a server, I just want something that is reproducible in the event i need to set-up or replace a new machine.

Comment: This isn't really inherent with Docker. The same could be said for nginx or any other software you wan't to automatically provision.

Answer (score 0):

this is basically what `docker-machine` does for you https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/

and other "orchestration" systems will make this automated and easier, as well

Comment: so Docker machine allow to run a containerized app on every VPS host ?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of solutions to this with no real one size fits all answer.

Chef and Puppet are the popular configuration management tools that typically use a centralized server. Ansible is another option that typically runs without a server and just connects with ssh to configure the host. All three of these works very similarly, so if your concern is simply managing the CM server, Ansible may be the best option for you.

For VM's Vagrant is the typical solution and it can be combined with other tools like Ansible to provision the VM after creating it.

In the cloud space, there's tools like Terraform or vendor specific tools like CloudFormation.

Docker is working on a project called Infrakit to deploy infrastructure the way compose deploys containers. It includes hooks for several of the above tools, including Terraform and Vagrant. For  your own requirements, this may be overkill.

Lastly, for designing VM images, Docker recently open sourced their Moby project which creates the VM image containing a minimal container OS, the same one used under the covers in Docker for Windows, Docker for Mac, and possibly some of the cloud hosing providers.

Answer (score 0):

We automate Docker installation on hosts using [Ansible](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_getting_started.html) + [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). Given the propper SSH access, provisioning new Docker hosts is a matter of triggering a Jenkins job.